# xdebug: %H %R specifiers not working on Windows XP?

Tags: settings, xdebug

I want the xdebug.profile_output_name ini setting to accept the %H and/or %R specifiers on my Windows XP box. It seems xdebug doesn't do anything with them. Is this known behaviour for xdebug on Windows machines?

Apache: 2.2.9
PHP: 5.2.10
xdebug: php_xdebug-2.0.5-5.2.dll

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, enabling register_long_arrays in php.ini fixed this, although it was on a CentOS 5.3 server, not a Windows one.

EDIT: I've submitted this to the XDebug bug tracker at http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=478, and it looks like it is a confirmed issue - either `register_long_arrays` or `register_globals` (ick) must currently be turned on for `%R` or `%H` to work.